# RestAssured Assertion failing

Tags: cucumber, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath, feature-file

Feature File Snippet:

Then The value of messages.type should be ERROR

Actual Service Response:
"messages": [
        {
            "type": "ERROR"
        }]

Console Log:

JSON path messages.type doesn't match.
Expected: a string containing "ERROR"
  Actual: [ERROR]

I have tried removing double quotes from ERROR parameter mentioned in feature file, it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

SInce you not provided the code you used, this can be due to the fact that you dint convert the json response to a String . Please try with below code since it has an example to how to convert Json to String .

```
public void jsonPathExample() {
        Response response=given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).get("http://localhost:3000/posts");
          //we need to convert response as a String 
        JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(response.asString());
        String actualtype = jsonPath.getString("type");
//Then do your assertion
    }
```